# Unit root tests, testing with trends or without?

Tags: econometrics, trend

I have an assignment, i have three data sets. It appears two sets have trends, and the other does not. When i undertake unit root tests do i need to estimate them all with a trend or can i interpret them as unique series?

Edit: I have been given data on the spot rate of 5 countries in terms of USD. CPI data for the US, and finally CPI data of 5 countries. I have put the time series data into the natural log form and graphed it,two series appear to have trends.

Comment: You may need to provide more information about the three time series to get a proper answer.

Comment: Are you asking what would happen if you were to do the trendy test on the trend-free data?